# Simple injector how to register /resolve collection of singletons against same interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

So I have this class that I would like to register multiple singletons off, where I would like to distinguish between them (after resolving from container) using the "ExchangeName" property

```
public interface IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider
{
    void DoSomethingWithDb();
    string ExchangeName { get; }
}

public class GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider : IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider
{
    private object _syncLock = new object();

    public GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider(string exchangeName)
    {
        ExchangeName = exchangeName;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithDb()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {

        }
    }

    public string ExchangeName { get; }
}
```

And this is what I have in simple injector to register a collection

```
var container = new Container();
container.Collection.Register(new[]
{
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>(
        () => new GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider("A"), container),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>(
        () => new GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider("B"), container)
});
container.Verify();
```

This all looks cool

But when I try and resolve the collection like this

```
var globalExchangeRateLimitProviders =
    container.GetAllInstances<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>();
```

I get the following error

[image]

> No registration for type IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>> could be found.

I mean I can guess why this is, it is due to the fact that what I currently have registered is a `IEnumerable<Registration>` not `IEnumerable<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>`

But I am just not sure how to wire up SimpleInjector to give me what I want here. What do I need to do in order to register the above an get an `IEnumerable<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>` out of the container?

How can I achieve this using SimpleInjector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the wrong `Register<T>` overload. You are actually calling `Register<T>(params T[] singletons)`, instead of calling `Register<T>(IEnumerable<Registration> registrations)`. This causes the registrations to be made as a collection of `Registration` instances, instead of a collection of `IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider` instances, as can be seen when hovering over the verified container:

[image: Simple Injector's debug view showing the root registrations]

Instead, include the type of the collection when calling `Collection.Register`

```
var container = new Container();
container.Collection.Register<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>(new[]
    {
        Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>(
            () => new GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider("A"), container),
        Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IGlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider>(
            () => new GlobalExchangeRateLimitProvider("B"), container)
    });
container.Verify();
```